# How to move elpy interactive python shell from bottom to the side?

Tags: python, elpy

I am using [elpy](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy) as a python development environment. when I run a code in `interactive python shell`  it shows the output in the bottom of the window. Can I move this bottom `interactive python shell` to the side

Answer (score 1):

**From the Elpy buffer:**

If you do: switch to python shell with `C-c C-z` the interactive shell will open in a side window.

From then on when you  send buffer to python with `C-c C-c`, Emacs will send the code to that window.